# Caching WCF client-side with .NET4

Tags: wcf, caching, client-side

I have a set of entities which which will be retrieved from service.
Some of them are static, so i decided to create a client-side cache.
But i can not find the point to insert caching. I have svcutil generated proxies and i need to enable caching for some of them (not all).
My point is to make some mechanism, that will work in channelFactory/clientBase level and will cache all required entities.

What i want:

- transparent caching without business logic changing (in common or at all)
- configuring cacheable entities with some kind of attribute: [Cacheable]
- ability to add caching implementation: MemoryCache, DistributedCache

Answer (score 1):

Whereas, it's very easy to create a Caching Attribute using `IOperationInvoker` on the service (check an example [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/05/17/wcf-extensibility-ioperationinvoker.aspx)), it's very difficult to do the same on client side.

The best example that I've seen is from Paolo Salvatori, available [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/paolos/archive/2011/04/05/how-to-use-a-wcf-custom-channel-to-implement-client-side-caching.aspx). Great solution, but I finally gave up because of the complexity. I turned myself to a generic wrapper for WCF calls. There are still manual tasks but it's simpler and I can easily manage it.

Answer (score 0):

what about caching with Castle Windsor integration facility? you can intercept and implement cache client side (i did it). weak side: i think this project is not well documented, and also i dont really know how alive it is.

http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.WCF-Integration-Facility.ashx