# How to implicitly cache response messages in WCF Request-response pattern?

Tags: c#, winforms, wcf, memorycache

How can I implicitly cache response messages within a consumer application that invokes one or multiple underlying services using WCF and a Request-Response message exchange pattern without modifying the code of the application in question? My option for caching is memorycache.

Scenario :

- Windows form application as Consumer
- 30 plus services hosted in IIS
- Both client and services under my control

I'm currently looking at the following items for implementation :

- BeforeSendRequest / BeforeSendReply
- Or custom binding that I could probably annotate in every Service

I would like to hear some options if you have in mind. Thanks!

Comment: I do not see how it would be possible to implement a feature such as memory caching without modifying any code. Did you mean you only don't want to modify the client application, and modifying the services is possible?

Comment: @allonym, you are absolutely correct. I don't want to pollute client application with any wrapper/logic before calling the service method. What exactly I want is to intercept those client proxy calls and check if those requesting object is already exist in the cache, if not proceed with the request to service. That is the reason why I put an options of BeforeSendRequest/BeforeSendReply or may be through custom extension or behavior where I could just plug it in in client proxy. I hope I answered your question clearly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Caching WCF client-side with .NET4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17021035/caching-wcf-client-side-with-net4)